# Remove tag text (but keep tag) in BeautifulSoup4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

This is the inverse from the many "remove tag but keep content" questions - how do I remove the text inside a tag (e.g. `<span foo="bar">text I don't want</span>` but keep the tag (i.e. `<span foo="bar"></span>`)?

Answer (score 0):

Just set `tag.string` to an empty string. Alternatively, use `tag.string.replace_with()`.

```
    bs = BeautifulSoup(html)
    for tag in bs.find_all('span'):
        # Strip all text by setting it to an empty string
        tag.string = ""
        # Or strip all text by replacing the string
        tag.string.replace_with("")
```